# How to implement interface properties with the same name and different type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Any suggestions about how to make this code compilable?

```kotlin
interface I1 {
    val id: String
}
interface I2 {
    val id: Integer
}
class Test: I1, I2 {
    //???
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-could-one-implement-multiple-interfaces-with-same-property-name/16494) can help you

Comment: What would you like to accomplish? How do you see the user of class `Test` using it? How would the user know the type of `id`?

Comment: @Elikill58, in my example, the types are different. It is matters.

Comment: @Tarmo this is just an example. It will take a long for me, to explain my domain, and why I am faced with this issue.

Comment: Those questions where rather meant as rhetoric ones to make you see that you can't do it per se, cause the resulting class would not be usable. Depending on you concrete case you would have to find a different solution. Without knowing the concrete case, it's hard to offer a nice solution.

Comment: Ok, folks, my question is incorrect. It really can't be done. Thank you for your time ;)